# Is the luceneappengine jar complete or do I need to download more jars

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, lucene

I download the [Lucene App Engine (LAE) jar from maven](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.googlecode.luceneappengine%22%20AND%20a%3A%22luceneappengine%22) based on instructions found [here](https://code.google.com/p/luceneappengine/wiki/Downloads). Having downloaded the jar and imported it into my project, I expect the following lines to work but I am getting compile errors for `IndexWriterConfig`

```
GaeDirectory directory = new GaeDirectory();//create a default index
IndexWriterConfig config = GaeLuceneUtil.getIndexWriterConfig(LUCENE_VERSION, analyzer);//get configuration
IndexWriter w = new IndexWriter(directory, config);//get the writer
/* now use Apache Lucene like you're used to */
```

Also where should I get the `analyzer` from? Eclipse is not finding a class for it. Do I have to import lucene in addition to luceneappengine?

The project claims there is an example with source, but I cannot open the source of the example to see the code. When I click on source it loops back to the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I have to import lucene in addition to luceneappengine?

Yep.  You can see that dependency in the Maven example at https://code.google.com/p/luceneappengine/ , where dependencies on lucene core and common analyzers are made explicit.

> The project claims there is an example with source, but I cannot open
>   the source of the example to see the code. When I click on source it
>   loops back to the site.

https://code.google.com/p/lucene-appengine-examples/source/browse/src/main/java/com/googlecode/lucene/IndexServlet.java works for me and starts

```
package com.googlecode.lucene;

import com.googlecode.luceneappengine.GaeDirectory;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer;
```

(then a ton more imports of `org.apache.lucene` stuff) confirming that, yep, `luceneappengine` is an **add-on** to `lucene` proper, and you still need to import plenty from the latter (core, and common analyzers).

Comment: In the example code, lines 118-150 is not compiling.  Is it because I am using Version.LUCENE_5_0_0?

Comment: More specifically `QueryParser` cannot be resolved. In lines `StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
   QueryRescorer queryParser = new QueryParser(LuceneWorker.LUCENE_VERSION, "title", analyzer);`

Comment: QueryParser's been around forever, and in the example it's imported at line 15, `import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser;` -- you're saying that line succeeds just fine but then you can't **use** QueryParser?!

Comment: No the import did **not** succeed.

Comment: I found the import. It turns out it was a jar all by itself